# Robocopy - will it produce corrupted files if I stop it before it finishes?

Tags: c++, c, robocopy

Let's say I run robocopy, using winapi's CreateProcess function. If I stop the process before it exits, will this create corrupted files of any kind? For example I have a maximum of 10000ms to run robocopy, before I have to stop it and do something else.

For example:

```
DWORD state = WaitForSingleObject(robocopyProcessInfo.hProcess, 10000);

if (state == WAIT_FAILED || state == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
     CloseHandle(robocopyProcessInfo.hProcess);
     CloseHandle(robocopyProcessInfo.hThread);

     return;
}
```

If this times out, is it possible to end up with corrupted files at the destination, and if so how do I prevent this, or solve this problem in a different way? I couldn't find any argument for robocopy that specifies timeout or something similar, or any info about this topic.

Comment: Why call an external process that you'll struggle to control rather than copying the files yourself?

Comment: Fyi, this isn't stopping any thread nor process. All this does is frees the handles used to monitor them. Terminating the process (which I assume you created somewhere with `CreateProcess`) is done with [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess).

Comment: the question has nothing to do with C++ or C